# Add machine name to Active Directory group

Tags: active-directory

How do you add a machine name, the name with the trailing dollar sign that is automatically added to the machine, e.g. DOMAIN\SERVERNAME$, to an AD group?

Comment: Choose Computers instead of Users & Groups?

Answer (score 4):

Begin by adding a member to the group, like you normally would.  To add a machine account to a group, you have to ensure that in the `Select Users` dialog, under `Object Types`, that `Computers` is selected.  Then enter the machine name, without the $.  It should validate.